# Angular 5 Download DOCX file from Database

Tags: arrays, angular5

I have WORD DOCX file in binary format in my SQL database.
I'm using c# WEB API controller to connect to database from get byte array and send it to my front end as string datatype.
Then trying to download it on a button click in my Angular 5 application.

Please find the code below,

WEB API Controller:

```
public Model testFunction()
{
  byte[] inputWORDBytes = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
  Model model = new Model();
  model.WORDFile = inputWORDBytes;
  return model;
}
```

C# Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public byte[] WORDFile { get; set; }
}
```

Angular Model:

```
export interface Model {
    WORDFile : string;
}
```

Angular Component:

```
//Inside service method call
let binWord = atob(model.WORDFile);
let bytesWord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < binWord.length; i++) {
  bytesWord.push(binWord.charCodeAt(i));
}
let documentWORD: Uint32Array = new Uint32Array(bytesWord);

var blob = new Blob([documentWORD], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```

It downloads a word file but it is corrupted.